# How to use Lucene FieldCache for search speed improvement?

Tags: java, caching, lucene, full-text-search

I am using Lucene 3.6 and i am trying to implement FieldCache. I have seen some posts but did not get any clear idea. Can anyone please suggest me any link where i can find proper example of FieldCache and how to use it while searching.

Answer (score 0):

You dont typically use it directly, it is an internal API used by Lucene.

If you are extending Lucene's search API and need to use it, you will need to provide more details.